# Intellisense not appearing for DbSet class

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

My intellisense is not appearing for my DbSet class.

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
IEnumerable<Element> elements = db.Elements.[NO INTELLISENSE HERE]
```

The fully qualified name is `System.Data.Entity.DbSet`.

I have a reference to `System.Web.Mvc` at the top of my file.

The code compiles and runs without any issues.

What is the problem here and/or how to I go about debugging it and then fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the entity framework lib (to the project where your code resides).

Comment: I installed EntityFramework using the package manager and it fixed this. I still don't understand how the code itself would work if those references were missing.